# Down arrow with many lines using mhchem package

Tags: mhchem, chemistry, chemstyle

I am using `mhchem` package for a chemistry chapter in my document. I have a section in which there is a down arrow with many lines, as shown in image below.   
 
[image] 
 
 The code for this that I've wrote so far is like this;

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage [version=4] {mhchem}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\ce{Mg} \qquad strongest reducing agent, more readily becomes oxidized\\
\ce{Al}\\
\ce{Mg}\\
\ce{Zn}\\
\ce{Fe}\\
\ce{Pb}\\
\ce{Cu}\\
\ce{Ag} \qquad weakest reducing agent, least readily becomes oxidized \\

\end{document}
```

Please tell me that how can I do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could exploit `\downarrow` that's extensible:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage [version=4] {mhchem}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\noindent
$\left\downarrow
\begin{tabular}{l@{\qquad}l@{}}
\ce{Mg} & strongest reducing agent, more readily becomes oxidized\\
\ce{Al}\\
\ce{Mg}\\
\ce{Zn}\\
\ce{Fe}\\
\ce{Pb}\\
\ce{Cu}\\
\ce{Ag} & weakest reducing agent, least readily becomes oxidized
\end{tabular}
\right.$

\end{document}
```

[image]